# MATLAB enumerated switch statement always goes into first case

Tags: matlab, oop, enums, switch-statement

I am trying to use an enumerated class to dictate behaviour in a switch statement in another class's constructor. So, what I have is the following:

From my enumerated class:

```
classdef(Enumeration) MyScheme
    enumeration
        Scheme1, Scheme2, Scheme3
    end
end
```

and then the class that uses this:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    methods
        function c = MyClass(scheme, varargin)
            switch(scheme)
                case MyScheme.Scheme1
                    % Do stuff with varargin
                case MyScheme.Scheme2
                    % Do different stuff with varargin
                case MyScheme.Scheme3
                    % Do yet something else with varargin
                otherwise
                    err('Not a valid scheme');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, no matter what scheme I pass in to the constructor, it just goes straight into the first case. When I add a breakpoint and step through and manually check equality (`scheme == MyScheme.Scheme1`), it recognizes that the two are not equal and returns 0 for this check, so I do not understand at all why it would still enter first case. If I change the order of the cases it will just enter whichever one is first. As far as I can tell, this is identical syntax to the **Using Enumerations in a Switch Statement** section of [this MATLAB help document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html), but perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem in R2013a:

#### MyScheme.m

```
classdef MyScheme
    enumeration
        Scheme1, Scheme2, Scheme3
    end
end
```

#### MyClass.m

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        x
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(scheme)
            switch(scheme)
                case MyScheme.Scheme1
                    obj.x = 10;
                case MyScheme.Scheme2
                    obj.x = 20;
                case MyScheme.Scheme3
                    obj.x = 30;
                otherwise
                    error('Not a valid scheme');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

which is working correctly:

```
>> MyClass(MyScheme.Scheme2)
ans = 
  MyClass with properties:

    x: 20
```

If for some reason it is still not working for you, a workaround would be to compare their string representation instead:

```
switch char(scheme)
    case char(MyScheme.Scheme1)
        obj.x = 10;
    case char(MyScheme.Scheme2)
        obj.x = 20;
    case char(MyScheme.Scheme3)
        obj.x = 30;
    otherwise
        error('Not a valid scheme');
end
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'm in R2010a (64-bit) and do not have access to R2013a to check, so perhaps it is a version thing. It definitely does not work for me, but casting it to a string seems to do the trick. Thank you, again, for your help!